# Joining a public WiFi made the owner able to send me a Facebook friend request. How?

Tags: security, facebook, wifi-hotspot, privacy

I walked by a bar with free, unsecured WiFi. My device auto-joined it, and a minute later I had a friend request on Facebook from that very bar.

How did they get my Facebook identity just from joining their WiFi? It feels a bit intrusive for them to do that, and honestly it makes me a bit paranoid about how much information about me is made available to the owner of the bar so easily.

Comment: Public WiFis are often unsecured. Everyone can then sniff on anyone else's traffic and analyse it using simple tools. Use VPNs if you want to secure your private data when on a public WiFi.

Comment: Unsecured WiFi doesn't fully explain it. Facebook is all-HTTPS, at least in the US. Some other mechanism(s) is/are at work. One possibility is that some app has associated your device WiFi MAC address (publicly visible to anyone in range regardless of TLS, VPN, etc.) with your Facebook account, and the bar (or someone in it) had access to that association.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep for comment, sadly - but my guess is that this could be [Facebook beacon](https://web.facebook.com/business/a/facebook-bluetooth-beacons) (not necessarily BT, they work with WiFi too).